# Clustered index on a uniqueidentifier field

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I am trying to visualize the table rows arrangement when the pk is on a uniqueidentifier field. I know rows are stored in a 'sorted' fashion based on the value of the column. Can someone please explain how that works (may be with some example) in case of a uniqueidentifier? Or point me to a link with a solid example instead of mere definition?

Comment: With a uniqueidentifier, you get **really bad** index fragmentation since those values are by definition very much random. The uniqueidentifier represents a 16-byte numerical value on which it's sorted

Comment: SQL Server has a sequential GUID to avoid that issue.